# Different md5 hash results in Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, hash, md5, digest

I'm trying to translate existing code from java into JavaScript (node.js to be specific). Creating an md5 hash of the same String in both languages leads to the following different results:

In **Java** `Arrays.toString(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("test".getBytes()));`

returns

> [9, -113, 107, -51, 70, 33, -45, 115, -54, -34, 78, -125, 38, 39, -76, -10]

while in **JS** `crypto.createHash("md5").update("test", "ascii").digest();`

returns

> [9, 143, 107, 205, 70, 33, 211, 115, …]

using crypto 1.0.1
Can anyone explain this to me? I already played around with different encodings, but it did not affect the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using signed bytes in Java.
It's actually the same.
I would vote for the unsigned version, but if you have to be compatible with the Java version just `arr.map(function(e) {return e >= 128 ? e - 256 : e})`

Comment: oh well, that does make sense, because im actually using a node.js Buffer, the provided mapping function does not change that behavior. Never the less, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Both hashes are same. Since the unsigned/signed types you are seeing different numbers but they has same values. Try casting values to unsigned.